# Doctrine ManyToOne does not cascade persist

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm trying to do the following :

```
/**
 * @Entity
 */
class Player {

    /**
     *@Column
     *@Id
     */
     private $uuid; //gets assigned a Uuid in the constructor

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Team", cascade={"persist"})
     * @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="uuid")
     */
     private $team;

     public function setTeam(Team $team) {
         $this->team = $team;
     }

     //...
}

/**
 * @Entity
 */
class Team {
    /**
     * @Column
     * @Id
     */
    private $uuid; //gets assigned a Uuid in the constructor

    //...
}

$player = new Player;
$team = new Team;
$player->setTeam($team);
$entityManager->persist($player);
$entityManager->flush();
```

The team is not persisted in to the database.

I do not want to call `$entityManager->persist($team)` as in my case, the Team is created in a part of the code where I don't have knowledge of persistence.

My expectation is that the `cascade={"persist"}` option should make the EntityManager also persist the Team.
Why is my expectation wrong or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I was not mistaken... This works as expected!

Taking a second look, there was never a flush after a added the Team to the Player.
Reading my own question again, I realised what that I missed it...
I should talk to my rubber duck more often, so it seems...